# VueJS on/off or hide/show toggle button based on other buttons situation

Tags: css, vue.js, toggle, show-hide

I have a table which includes the days of the week and plus, Everyday, Weekdays and Weekend options. Every row has 2 `select` items to select start time and end time for updates. At the end of each row there is a toggle button to enable and disable that specific day. Users are allowed to select each day individually or they may select Everyday option. When they enable the toggle, the disabled select elements become enabled so they can pick time for that specific day.

Here is how it looks;
[image]

As shown above, users may select Weekdays and Weekend together and this should be equal to Everyday right? So what I want to do is when they enable Weekdays and Weekend together, Everyday toggle should be enabled and the other two become disabled again.

Here is my data and my method;

```
data() {
        return {
        everydayCheck: false,
        weekdaysCheck: false,
        weekendCheck: false,
        customCheck: false,
        mondayCheck: false,
        tuesdayCheck: false,
        wednesdayCheck: false,
        thursdayCheck: false,
        fridayCheck: false,
        saturdayCheck: false,
        sundayCheck: false,
        }
    },

methods: {
       isDisabled: function(){
         if(this.everydayCheck){   return !this.everydayCheck;   }
         else if(this.weekdaysCheck){   return !this.weekdaysCheck;   }
         else if(this.weekendCheck){   return !this.weekendCheck; }
         else if(this.customCheck){   return !this.customCheck;   }
         else if(this.mondayCheck){   return !this.mondayCheck;   }
         else if(this.tuesdayCheck){   return !this.tuesdayCheck;   }
         else if(this.wednesdayCheck){   return !this.wednesdayCheck;   }
         else if(this.thursdayCheck){   return !this.thursdayCheck;   }
         else if(this.fridayCheck){   return !this.fridayCheck;   }
         else if(this.saturdayCheck){   return !this.saturdayCheck;   }
         else if(this.weekdaysCheck && this.weekendCheck){
             return this.everydayCheck, !this.weekdaysCheck, !this.weekendCheck;
         }
         else {  return !this.sundayCheck;   }
      },
   },
```

The last `else if` just before else says if weekendCheck and weekdaysCheck are true, turn the everydayCheck to true and make the other ones false, or am I wrong? It doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support functions that return multiple values. So the last `else if` before `else` is invalid

Comment: And how do you use the `isDisabled()` anyway? I can tell it only returns a boolean.

Comment: <input @click="isDisabled" v-model="weekdaysCheck" type="checkbox"> I use it like this. When the related checkbox is clicked, the function works like a toggle. It switches the data between true and false. Is there anyway that I can control when two checkboxes is checked? When the two of them is checked I need to go and enable the other one, then disable these two.

Comment: @Yashin Demirkaya I saw your problem right there. So this function `isDisabled` only runs if they toggle on weekdays, whereas you want this function to run on `everyday` and `weekend` as well, don't you?

Comment: I have isDisabled function for every table element, Everyday, Weekdays, Weekend and the other 7. Whichever of them is selected, the function checks it and toggles it. So Weekend and Weekdays can be selected at the same time, if so, I need to trigger the function to go and select the everyday.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(this.weekdaysCheck && this.weekendCheck){
             return this.everydayCheck, !this.weekdaysCheck, !this.weekendCheck;
         }
```

this is wrong, because you are returning 3 different things, and this is not supported in js.

trivially you can do:

```
else if(this.weekdaysCheck && this.weekendCheck){
   changeWeek();
   return
}
```

and add a method like this:

```
changeWeek: function(){
  this.everydayCheck=!this.everydayCheck,
  this.weekdaysCheck=!this.weekdaysCheck,
  this.weekendCheck=!this.weekendCheck;
}
```

but this will be not really good code. my advice is trying to generate the input with a v-for statement, starting from an object like this:

```
data(){
 return{
  inputs: [
   {
    id:everydaycheck,
    active:false,
    ...
   },
   ...
  ]
 }
}
```

then you can make a function that is dynamic:

```
<template v-for="input in inputs">
  <input @click="isDisabled($event) v-model="input.active" :key="input.id" 
  id="input.id">
</template>
```

and in your function:

```
methods:
 isDisabled(event) {
  let id=event.target.getAttribute('id')
  inputs.forEach((input)=>{
  if(input.id == id) {
   input.active=!input.active
  }
  })

 }
```

Comment: Yeah I messed it up with the return statement... Now I changed the function a little bit and fixed pretty much everything except some little stuff. Thanks for the support

Comment: if you need more help, i can try ;)